# What might be the problem with this Redux (react) App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, store

I am having trouble with my code, but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

I am trying to make a project on a single App component, to get a better understanding, but I can't get the `heroes` state.

I'd like to get a better understanding of Redux, and after this project, I'll separate the files, but I found it easier to just use one app to start.

> My Code

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const initialState = {
  heroes: [
    {id: 1, name: 'Superman'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Batman'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Robin'},
    {id: 4, name: 'Spiderman'},
    {id: 5, name: 'Thor'}
  ]
}
const GET_HEROES = 'GET_HEROES';

const getHeroes = () => {
  return {
    type: GET_HEROES,
    text: 'Getting all the heroes'
  }
}

const heroReducer = function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case GET_HEROES:
      console.log(state);
      return { ...state }
    default:
      console.log(state);
      return state
  }
}
const rootReducer = combineReducers ({
  hero: heroReducer
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(thunk));

class App extends React.Component {



  componentDidMount() {
    getHeroes();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
        <ul>
          {[1,2,3].map(item => (
            <li>{item}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </Provider>
    );
  };
}

App.propTypes = {
  getHeroes: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  hero: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default (App);
```

Comment: Please add the error in your question.

Comment: Can you please point to where you are trying to get the `heroes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application cannot get state of heroes because it doesn't connect to redux. You could use 'connect' function to make connection between app and redux middleware. You also need to add mapStatetoProps() & mapDispatchtoProps() in connect functions.

- mapStatetoProps(), in order to connect App commponent with redux.
- mapDispatchProps(), in order to dispatch action redux on App componnent.

The code should be like this:

`index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './App.js';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const initialState = {
  heroes: [
    {id: 1, name: 'Superman'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Batman'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Robin'},
    {id: 4, name: 'Spiderman'},
    {id: 5, name: 'Thor'}
  ]
}
const GET_HEROES = 'GET_HEROES';

const getHeroes = () => {
  return {
    type: GET_HEROES,
    text: 'Getting all the heroes'
  }
}

const heroReducer = function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case GET_HEROES:
      console.log(state);
      return { ...state }
    default:
      console.log(state);
      return state
  }
}
const rootReducer = combineReducers ({
  hero: heroReducer
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

const app = (
  <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
  </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'));
```

`app.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.ongetHeroes();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello world</h1>
        <ul>
        {[1,2,3].map(item => (
          <li>{item}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  };
}

App.propTypes = {
  getHeroes: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  hero: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    heroes: state.hero.heroes
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    ongetHeroes : () => dispatch(getHeroes()),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStatetoProps, mapDispatchtoProps)(App);
```

Comment: '''×
Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(App) in connect options.

Comment: Provider of 'react-redux' has props for store redux `<Provider store={store}>`. You can see in App component

Comment: @GellértPuskás I just make an update for my answer for further correct. You could refer to it

Comment: I got the problem. I had to make the Provider tags in the index.js if I have only the App.js, and not separate components.
Thanks for all of ya.

Comment: <Provider />  should be top component. It wrapper all of components in the application. Then, if one component need to connect Redux, it should wrapper with function connect() i.e.:connect(mapStatetoProps, mapDispatchtoProps)(App) at exporting component.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [connect](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect)...

Example usage for your code:

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    getHeros: getHeros
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        heros: state.heros
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,  mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: I tought connect only needed when i make another component. To connect App component

Comment: The connect() function connects a React component to a Redux store. Please read [this](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect).